# Как перебрать все комбинации из чисел и арифметических операций?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

У меня есть задача, и хотелось бы узнать как её можно реализовать с помощью C++:

> Есть цифры 1,3,4,6. Нужно написать программу реализующую последовательный перебор этих цифр и знаков четырех элементарных арифметических операций (сложение, вычитание, умножение и деление), чтобы получилось выражение с результатом 24.

Нужно именно как-то перебором это реализовать что бы подставлялись цифры
и операции над ними последовательно а когда будет 24 перебор остановился и выдал результат.

У меня вообще нет идей как это можно реализовать подскажите пожалуйста или если можно напишите код или хотя бы кусок кода.

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: В выражении скобок быть не может, правильно?

Comment: Да скобки тоже могут быть

Comment: Допустима ли конкатенация цифр в числа?

Comment: Нет только 4 разных цифры конкатенации быть не может и каждую цифру можно использовать только один раз

Comment: Тогда это 4 числа, а не цифры

Comment: @Kromster я бы с радостью привел какие то свои наработки но я понятия не имею как это можно реализовать по этому прошу хотя бы дать намек или хотя бы псевдокод как это вообще делается

Comment: Если `(14-6)*3` не подходит, тогда `6/(1-3/4)`

Comment: @vp_arth А смысл искать подходящее выражение на глазок? Это же надо запрограммировать.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, 4fun.. интересная же задачка) Программировать дольше)

Comment: @user1 Деление с отбрасыванием дробной части или нет?

Comment: Я вот не знаю, как это на c++ запрограммировать. Реализовывать класс рациональных дробей? Вводить эпсилон? Хотя, получается, что знаю) Проще всего, наверное, реализовать перебор на базе ОПН, чтобы со скобками не заморачиваться. Тогда правильным решением будет что-то вроде `6 1 3 4 / - /`

Comment: Я бы вообще все возможные комбинации скобок вручную вписал.

Comment: А цифры только по одному разу можно использовать? И все они должны быть использованы?

Comment: Каждую цифру можно использовать только один раз и каждая из них должна быть использована

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Код писать не буду, опишу алгоритм.

Перво-наперво, определяетесь, что будете делать с потерей точности при делении(в числах с плавающей запятой). Предлагаю 2 варианта:

- Реализовать класс рациональных чисел, в котором определить числитель/знаменатель, арифметические операции с автосокращением и т.п.
- Сравнение с результатом проводить с учётом погрешности (Ввести так называемый epsilon)

*Во втором случае, теоретически могут появиться неверные решения*

Далее, ознакомливаетесь, что такое обратная польская нотация...

```
1 + 2 * 3 === 1 2 3 * +
```

В вашем случае, оно сводится к выражению из четырёх чисел и трёх арифм.операций в формах:

```
a0 a1 a2 a3 op0 op1 op2  # линейное вычисление  
a0 a1 op1 a2 op2 a3 op3  # выражение вида a-b-c-d  
a0 a1 op1 a2 a3 op2 op3  # выражение вида (a+b)/(c-d)
```

В более сложном задании придётся перебрать все формы. Возможно проще перебирать вообще все, включая некорректные, но можно и формализовать.

Осуществляете перебор всех перестановок чисел 4!=24 и всех возможных операций. Операций всего 4(+-*/), выполняются 3 раза. Итого перебор операций 4^3=64, а всего полный перебор (трёх форм) займёт `3*24*64` = около 5000 итераций.

На каждой итерации вычисляете выражение и сравниваете его с нужным результатом.

На базе найденного выражения из ОПН форматируете вывод решения.

---

ЗЫ: На этапе вычислений, не забудьте про edge cases. Деление на нуль нужно обработать (перейти к следующей итерации).

---

Демонстрация алгоритма на javascript:

```js
class OPN {
  constructor() { this.stack = []; }
  __computeFn(a, b, op) {
    switch (op) {
      case '+': return a + b;
      case '-': return a - b;
      case '*': return a * b;
      case '/':
        if (b === 0) throw new Error('Division by zero');
        return a / b;
      default: throw new Error(`Unknown operator ${op}`);
    }
  }
  __renderFn(a, b, op) {
    return `(${a} ${op} ${b})`;
  }
  __process(tokens, fn) {
    for (let token of tokens) {
      if (typeof token === 'number') {
        this.stack.push(token);
      } else { // assume operation
        if (this.stack.length < 2) throw new Error('Incorrect expression');
        let b = this.stack.pop();
        let a = this.stack.pop();
        this.stack.push(fn(a, b, token));
      }
    }
    if (this.stack.length != 1) throw new Error('Incorrect expression');
    return this.stack.pop();
  }
  calc(tokens) {
    return this.__process(tokens, this.__computeFn);
  }
  render(tokens) {
    return this.__process(tokens, this.__renderFn);
  }
}


class Permutator {
  constructor() { this.current = []; this.used = [];}
  getAllFor(input) {
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      let item = input.splice(i, 1)[0]; // take item

      this.used.push(item); // use item
      if (input.length == 0) this.current.push(this.used.slice());
      this.getAllFor(input);
      this.used.pop(); // restore state

      input.splice(i, 0, item); // restore item
    }
    return this.current;
  }
}

let calc = new OPN;
let permutator = new Permutator;

let numbers = [1, 3, 4, 6];
let ops = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
const EPS = 1e-6;
function find () {
  let solutions = [];
  for (let perm of permutator.getAllFor(numbers)) {
    for (let op1 of ops) {
      for (let op2 of ops) {
        for (let op3 of ops) {
          let forms = [
            [perm[0], perm[1], perm[2], perm[3], op1, op2, op3],
            [perm[0], perm[1], op1, perm[2], perm[3], op2, op3],
            [perm[0], perm[1], op1, perm[2], op2, perm[3], op3],
          ];
          for (let form of forms) {
            try {
              let res = calc.calc(form);
              if (Math.abs(24 - res) < EPS) solutions.push(form);
            } catch(e) {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return solutions;
}

let solutions = find();
solutions.forEach(solution => console.log('Solution: ', calc.render(solution)));
```

Comment: может быть что можно применить только одну или две из этих операций ко всем парам

Comment: Ну не. `1 2 + 3 4 - *` - 4 числа, 3 оператора, а под ваш шаблон не подходит. Так что вы не все выражения перебираете.

Comment: Вы правы, поторопился, 4 аргумента позволяют разветвить нить вычислений)) Но правильное решение мой алгоритм находит(по счастливому стечению обстоятельств)

Comment: Это да.) По хорошему - надо как-то перебирать все валидные перестановки чисел и операторов в ОПН, хотя тут их видимо всего две...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, блин) Не две. асимметричность операций `-`, `/` позволяет ещё, как минимум форму `a b - c - d -`

Comment: Мда, точно.(...